# Where can I find event listings for Mumbai?

Tags: online-resources, nightlife, mumbai, events, mobile-apps

As I am in Mumbai for a month or two with my relatives, I want to explore complete Mumbai in this period, especially Mumbai's nightlife and foods, is there some tracking app of nightlife events or some website where events of Mumbai are logged?

Answer (score 2):

Mumbai is according to me the most best metropolitan city in India, the diversity it provides is limitless and incredible, and answering your question, I would say there are events held in Mumbai all the year, and there are many apps for checking the events, the best according to me would be :

1. [NearFox](http://nearfox.com)
2. [MeraEvents](http://www.meraevents.com/mumbai-events)

Check these websites, you will get day to day status on activities.

Comment: I know it's late but I think it'll be helpful in the future so you could also try [BookmyShow](https://in.bookmyshow.com/mumbai) to check all the latest events of the city.